# How to clean up the icegrid service that is not available？

Tags: load-balancing, ice

I use icegrid to do load balancing in a distributed system, but I am now in trouble, I passed Google, ICEApi are not resolved, I am in the icegrid cluster registered application instance publishing service, start multiple instances, but when some of my instances are not available, I can not clean up in the icegrid cluster is not available application instance!

Comment: Can you detail what prevents you from cleaning up/modifying the application from the IceGrid registry? You should be able to remove/add servers with the IceGrid administrative tools (icegridamin or IceGrid GUI) even if some IceGrid nodes are not online. Benoit.

Comment: I need to  implements code auto clean up it，when my application  hava mistack or my application auto moved other machine

Comment: i had solution，listener process by timertask can register and remove it